# Change iOS status bar color in ionic 2 app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

I am following the ionic 2 documentation for setting the iOS status bar color but it is not working. The status bar text is white which means on my white background it is invisible.

The code I have put in my app constructor is:

```js
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
```

I have imported StatusBar using:

```js
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
```

I have also checked that the cordova statusbar plugin is installed.

Comment: Would be better to post @ the [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/) instead of here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try like this add this in the config.xml, with the hex value of the color you want to set:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

For ngCordova or ionic-native you can use

```
  $cordovaStatusbar.styleColor('black');

  $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#000');
```

---

Or you check on the statusbar cordova plugin github page there are some ways to change the color of status bar: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

**For Android:**

```
if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#333");
}
```

**For iOS**

On iOS 7, when you set StatusBar.statusBarOverlaysWebView to false, you can set the background color of the statusbar by color name.

```
StatusBar.backgroundColorByName("red");
```

Supported color names are:

```
black, darkGray, lightGray, white, gray, red, green, blue, cyan, yellow, magenta, orange, purple, brown
```

**Or**
Sets the background color of the statusbar by a hex string.

```
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#C0C0C0");
```

CSS shorthand properties are also supported.

```
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#333"); // => #333333
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#FAB"); // => #FFAABB
On iOS 7, when you set StatusBar.statusBarOverlaysWebView to false, you can set the background color of the statusbar by a hex string (#RRGGBB).
```

On WP7 and WP8 you can also specify values as #AARRGGBB, where AA is an alpha value

Comment: did you tried all the methods returns in the plugins github page?

Comment: Yes. I have just noticed though that your suggestion does seem to be partially working in as much as the status bar appears with a black background as requested over the splash page but as the splash page fades away to reveal the white home page the status bar becomes invisible. Maybe it is being masked by my home page?

Comment: for reference I have written all the methods , still i don't know if all of them have any effect with your code or not, as for my latest project it worked with the preference only which i have return as the first one

Comment: That's it! I had misunderstood the statusBarOverlaysWebView I thought it had to be set to true. Setting it to false fixes the problem. Thanks you are wonderful!

Comment: As for the future reference if someone else has same problem, i have added `statusBarOverlaysWebView` property also

Comment: Note that if you use "ionic start", you may already have a "StatusBar.styleDefault();" in the platform ready part as an example. I had to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is include this directive in your `app.module.ts` (or whatever it is called).

This will handle status bar text color behavior **dynamically** through the whole application (no need to worry when and where to set something):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit, Optional } from '@angular/core'
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar'
import { Platform, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular'

@Directive({
  /* tslint:disable */
  selector: "ion-header",
  /* tslint:enable */
})
export class DynamicStatusBarDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public static isColorTooLight(colorString) {
    let rgb = DynamicStatusBarDirective.getRgbColor(colorString)

    if (rgb.a || (rgb.a < 0.2)) { // becoming too transparent
      return true
    }

    // contrast computation algorithm/approach: https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast
    let yiq = ((rgb.r * 299) + (rgb.g * 587) + (rgb.b * 114)) / 1000
    return yiq >= 128
  }

  public static getRgbColor(colorString): RGB {
    if (!colorString) {
      return null
    }

    let rgb: RGB = new RGB()

    if (colorString[ 0 ] === '#') { // seems hex color
      rgb.r = parseInt(colorString.substr(0, 2), 16)
      rgb.g = parseInt(colorString.substr(2, 2), 16)
      rgb.b = parseInt(colorString.substr(4, 2), 16)
    } else {
      let matchColors = /rgba?\(((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{1,2}|\d\d?)\s*,\s*?){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{1,2}|\d\d?)\s*,?\s*([01]\.?\d*?)?\)/
      let colors = matchColors.exec(colorString)
      if (colors) {
        rgb.r = parseInt(colors[ 1 ], 10)
        rgb.g = parseInt(colors[ 2 ], 10)
        rgb.b = parseInt(colors[ 3 ], 10)

        if (colors[ 4 ]) { // has transparency
          rgb.a = parseInt(colors[ 4 ], 10)
        }
      }
    }

    return rgb
  }

  public static getModalParent(nativeElm) {
    return nativeElm
      .parentNode // modal
      .parentNode // modal wrapper
      .parentNode // ion-modal
      .parentNode // ion-app, which handles background status bar
  }

  public static getHeaderBackgroundForMobile(nativeElm) {
    let header = nativeElm.querySelector('.toolbar-background')
    return window.getComputedStyle(header).backgroundColor
  }

  public ionViewEnterCallback: Function
  public modalCloseCallback: Function

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public elm: ElementRef,
    @Optional() public viewCtrl: ViewController,
  ) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ionViewEnterCallback = () => this.checkStatusBar()
    if (this.viewCtrl) {
      this.viewCtrl.willEnter.subscribe(this.ionViewEnterCallback)
    }
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.viewCtrl.willEnter.unsubscribe()
    this.viewCtrl.didLeave.unsubscribe()
  }

  public checkStatusBar(): void {
    if (!this.platform.is('ios')) {
      return
    }

    let nativeElm = this.elm.nativeElement

    if (this.viewCtrl.isOverlay) { // dealing with modal
      let parentNativeElm = DynamicStatusBarDirective.getModalParent(nativeElm)

      if (parentNativeElm) { // modal is open
        this.modalCloseCallback = () => this.setColor(window.getComputedStyle(parentNativeElm).backgroundColor)

        this.viewCtrl.didLeave.subscribe(this.modalCloseCallback)
      }

      if (this.platform.is('tablet')) {
        this.setColor(true) // for modals we are getting grey overlay, so need to set white background
        return
      }
    }

    let background = DynamicStatusBarDirective.getHeaderBackgroundForMobile(nativeElm)

    if (background) {
      this.setColor(background)
    }

  }

  public setColor(background: any): void {
    let isTooLight = DynamicStatusBarDirective.isColorTooLight(background)

    if (isTooLight) {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault()
    } else {
      this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent()
    }
  }
}

class RGB {
  r: number
  g: number
  b: number
  a?: number
}
```